# Sql to select count using dates

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using SQL Sever database, I am writing a query to select count of each option's RecordDate is found in surveys start and end date. If same any option found more than one time between the start and date, even then should be considered once.

```
tblOptions
----------------------------------
Option, RecardDate
----------------------------------  
o1 , 2016-01-01   
o1 , 2016-01-03   
o1 , 2016-05-08  
o2 , 2016-01-04   
o2 , 2016-01-01   
o2 , 2016-01-23     
o2 , 2016-05-15  
o3 , 2016-05-01  
o3 , 2016-05-02  
o3 , 2016-05-03     
o3 , 2016-04-04  
o3 , 2016-08-04


tblSurveys
----------------------------------
Surey, StartDate, EndDate
----------------------------------
s1 , 2016-01-01 , 2016-01-15
s2 , 2016-01-16 , 2016-01-31
s3 , 2016-05-01 , 2016-05-31
```

OUTPUT

```
Option,  Count 
-------------------
o1,  2             (Exp.:o1's recorddates found between two surveys star and end dates)     
o2,  3             (Exp.:o2's recorddates found between three surveys star and end dates)   
o3,  1             (Exp.:o3's recorddates found between one surveys star and end dates)
```

Comment: I think your Survey sample data is incorrect.  Are you supposed to have two `s3` Surveys, and the `EndDate` on the second Survey is before the `StartDate`.

Comment: Also, your `OUTPUT` contains errors as well, as the `o2` Options do not actually occur within the `StartDate` and `EndDate` of 3 different surveys, even if you do correct the `EndDate` on your second Survey.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by joining your data together and then grouping it together (The `distinct` option below) so you can count the unique combinations:

```
select [Option]                 -- You really should try to avoid using reserved
        ,count(1) as [Count]    -- words for your column names.
from (
    select distinct o.[Option]
                    ,s.Survey
                    ,s.StartDate
                    ,s.EndDate
    from @tblOptions o
        inner join @tblSurveys s
            on(o.RecardDate between s.StartDate and s.EndDate)
    ) a
group by [Option]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `COUNT(DISTINCT column)`

```
 SELECT  
     o.[Option], COUNT(DISTINCT Survey) [Count]
 FROM 
     tblOptions o
 INNER JOIN 
     tblSurveys s ON o.RecardDate BETWEEN s.StartDate AND s.EndDate
 GROUP BY 
     o.[Option]
```